# Drupal Views pager not working but results showing

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

We have a view setup to pickup the author/id

I see results, however, the pager is not working.  We have a pager set, but at the bottom, it says "No query was run".

In addition, if I use the contextual filter and type author/110, it shows nothing on the preview, even though the regular page shows results.

How can I filter and get the pager working.

Update:  I chose "Full Pager" and I can see it on the preview, but not the regular page after I save.  What could the problem be?

Update 2:  If I set pager id = 1 or higher, I can see it on the preview AND the regular page.  However, it has odd url values with commas, is page 2 really Page 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $pager variable within the templates (in views - theme information regarding active template name) might be missing or check for any views hook (there are min. 8 of them) that is changing the behavior of the views.